# permission denied after ssh command, even if password is correct

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi

I have connected a Raspberry Pi 2 to my laptop via network cable, and I am trying to transfer files from computer to raspi but command `ssh usr@blabla.local`, asks me for password and I am sure password is correct but I am getting `Permission denied, please try again`.

What can I do? I couldn't find a solution that fits my problem on internet.

Comment: How is SSH configured on the server side? Does it allow logging in with a password? Which account are you using? **Copy-paste** the exact command you ran and the full error messages.

Comment: ls ~/.ssh
id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
ssh pi@blabla.local
then asks for password and says permission denied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are 100% sure that there is no mistake in your password (and no encoding issue?), could be that the user account is locked in the raspberry pi. When a user account is locked, login attempts are rejected as "Password incorrect", even if the password was correct.

Or, if you are trying to log in as `root`, it could also be that `ssh` is running with the option "no root", effectively locking the `root` account when coming through `ssh`.

**EDIT/UPDATE** Answering question in comment

> if user account is locked, how can I fix it ?

Well... here you have basically two ways to proceed.

### 1. If you are in the system

NOTE: To alter anything of any other account that is not you, you need to perform the alteration as `root`

- To lock an account: `passwd -l <user>`
- To unlock an account: `passwd -u <user>`

Find more information about `passwd` in the [manpages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/passwd.1.html) (`man passwd`)

### 2. If you cannot access the system (but can alter the contents of the file system)

You are talking about Raspberry Pi2, so it means that you have your system for the Raspberry somewhere in your computer and you flash it to the Raspberry Pi.

If you were talking about a general computer, you would need to proceed with a LiveCD/LiveUSB and mount the system you want to alter.

**But the procedure is the same.**

NOTE: Treat `/` as the root (`/`) of your *target* system from now on.

Assuming your target system uses `shadow` file, the field reserved for the password hash in `/etc/passwd` contains `x` and the hash is actually in `/etc/shadow`.

If this hash is preceeded by an exclamation mark (`!`), it means that although the account is password protected, the account is locked. Remove this exclamation mark to have again the account unlocked when you boot into the system again (in the case of Raspberry Pi or any other embedded system, you need to flash this change into the module, of course)

Find more information about shadow file format [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lame/LAME/linux-admin-made-easy/shadow-file-formats.html)

Comment: if user account is locked, how can I fix it ?

Comment: @commandos2389 I have updated my answer to include your question there

Answer (score 1):

How did you do the network setup? @localhost would connect back to your laptop. You have to provide both interfaces with an IP within the same subnet (e.g. range 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 (IPv4)) and use the proper one to connect to.

(seems there was a mistake in the original question so the answer no longer fits)

Comment: Easier than manually assigning IPs would be to leverage a dhcp service and to connect both pi and laptop to a router.  I somehow missed the `localhost`, you are right that this is most likely the problem here.